# MarkLogic keeps crashing when I try to run cts.train() function

Tags: classification, marklogic

MarkLogic keeps crashing when I try to run `cts.train()` function. 
Is it my code or something else? Can you help me figure out what's wrong?

MarkLogic Server 8.0-6.4

```
    var labels = []

    var voi = cts.collectionQuery(["VehicleOfInterest"])
    for(var v in voi)
      labels.push({classes:{name:"car"}})

    v = cts.search(voi)

    var all = [].concat.apply([], [v.toArray()])
    var classifier = cts.train( all, labels, {classifierType: "supports", kernel:"simple", epsilon: 0.01} );
```

Sample node

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
      <RECORD__>1</RECORD__>
      <ENTRY_DATE>2/15/2017</ENTRY_DATE>
      <EXPIRY_DATE>2/15/2019</EXPIRY_DATE>
      <VEHICLE_MAKE>Toyota</VEHICLE_MAKE>
      <VEHICLE_MODEL>Corolla</VEHICLE_MODEL>
      <VEHICLE_YEAR>2013</VEHICLE_YEAR>
      <REGISTRATION>A29302843</REGISTRATION>
      <VIN>1234134</VIN>
      <LOCATION>MN</LOCATION>
      <CLAIM_NUMBER>12345678</CLAIM_NUMBER>
      <BACKGROUND___COMMENT>This is a test 1.</BACKGROUND___COMMENT>
      <ORIGINAL_SOURCE>INFORMANT</ORIGINAL_SOURCE>
      <RISK_CATEGORY>A1</RISK_CATEGORY>
      <LINKED_PHONE__>9382938402</LINKED_PHONE__>
    </root>
```

/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog.txt

```
Segmentation fault in thread 0x00007f6739864700
Thread 56 (Thread 0x7f67ec83d700 (LWP 6369)):
#0  0x00007f67e895379b in do_futex_wait.constprop.1 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f67e895382f in __new_sem_wait_slow.constprop.0 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007f67e89538cb in sem_wait@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x0000000004322515 in svc::Semaphore::wait ()
#4  0x000000000433f151 in svc::StarterThread::run ()
#5  0x000000000434166e in svc::Thread::top ()
#6  0x00000000043428b9 in runThread ()
#7  0x00007f67e894ddc5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x00007f67e7d3e6ed in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 55 (Thread 0x7f67ec79f700 (LWP 6377)):
#0  0x00007f67e7d3fb7f in accept4 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000433087a in svc::Socket::accept ()
#2  0x000000000402c8bf in xdmp::XDQPServerThread::run ()
#3  0x000000000434166e in svc::Thread::top ()
#4  0x00000000043428b9 in runThread ()
#5  0x00007f67e894ddc5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007f67e7d3e6ed in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 54 (Thread 0x7f67ec780700 (LWP 6378)):
#0  0x00007f67e8954bdd in nanosleep () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000000000433ed12 in svc::Thread::sleep ()
#2  0x00000000024cffa2 in xdmp::ClusterManager::clusterThread ()
#3  0x000000000434166e in svc::Thread::top ()
#4  0x00000000043428b9 in runThread ()
#5  0x00007f67e894ddc5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007f67e7d3e6ed in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 53 (Thread 0x7f673e7ff700 (LWP 6380)):
#0  0x00007f67e895379b in do_futex_wait.constprop.1 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f67e895382f in __new_sem_wait_slow.constprop.0 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007f67e89538cb in sem_wait@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x0000000004322515 in svc::Semaphore::wait ()
#4  0x00000000043445a6 in svc::PooledThread::run ()
#5  0x000000000434166e in svc::Thread::top ()
#6  0x00000000043428b9 in runThread ()
#7  0x00007f67e894ddc5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x00007f67e7d3e6ed in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

...
```

Comment: How are you running your code? Is this the complete code? Keep in mind v.toArray() could produce a large array, containing full documents; how large is collection `VehicleOfInterest`? And why are you iterating over `voi` to push items into `labels`?

Comment: i'm iterating voi to match the number of trainset with the labels

Comment: but you are iterating the collectionQuery object, not its search result..

Answer (score 0):

objects in labels are just in wrong format,
i changed it to something like this and works fine now

```
labels.push({ "name": "voi doc",
                "classes": [
                    {
                        "name": 'car',
                        "val": 1
                    }
                ]
            })
```